# How to show my Unique Indexes in my database

Tags: mysql

Hello guys i have a database which has 8 tables and in these 8 tables i have many unique

indexes and sample indexes but now i want to have the list of Unique indexes not sample

Indexes.I am using this command but its show both index and unique index.

Also i want to see that its not allowing the null values and repeated values.

```
HOW CAN I SHOW ONLY THE UNIQUE INDEXES ?

show Indexes from tab_name.

Result is list of both sample index and unique index


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Check the `information_schema` database

Comment: where its located in phpmyadmin

Comment: have you tried to google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name AS `Table`,
       index_name AS `Index`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY seq_in_index) AS `Columns`
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE table_schema = 'yourdatabasename' and index_name='PRIMARY'
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: i have given correct table name but still giving error massage that unknown table name

Comment: you  should not give table name just replace your database name to the above query